# Update statement to update ProjectId based on projectName where ProjectId does not exist.

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have two different databases from which I am attempting to merge data. Currently there are Projects and Users assigned to the Projects. Users can work on many (more than 1) projects at a time. Since the project's name can have spelling issues, I have performed an SSIS fuzzy grouping to match the data. Only problem is only one of the database keeps track of the ID that I will be using for the external program and the information of users working on a particular project can be overlapping.

```
ProjectName_1   Office_1    ContactName_1   contactid_1 ProjectID_1      department_1
MOW             NYC          John Caves                                 Producer
MOW             NYC          Jayson Brodie                              Producer
MOW             NYC          Jonathan Whites                            Editor
MOW             NYC          Dana Rutters                               Camera
MOW             NYC          ALI SAYMON          A00G8S5    A00MVDE 
MOW             NYC          CHRIS TY            A001NJ6    A00MVDE
```

Basically here, I want to update records where the ProjctId does not exist based on the Project Name. So the end result would be the following:

```
ProjectName_1   Office_1    ContactName_1   contactid_1 ProjectID_1      department_1
MOW             NYC          John Caves                     A00MVDE     Producer
MOW             NYC          Jayson Brodie                  A00MVDE     Producer
MOW             NYC          Jonathan Whites                A00MVDE     Editor
MOW             NYC          Dana Rutters                   A00MVDE     Camera
MOW             NYC          ALI SAYMON          A00G8S5    A00MVDE 
MOW             NYC          CHRIS TY            A001NJ6    A00MVDE
```

Keep in mind there are many different projects.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what seems to be a problem? Sounds like a simple `UPDATE`-`SELECT`-`JOIN` query. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Well I know I can do a simple update statement for 1 in particular but, I would need to select the Top 1 projectId where the ProjectName matches and match it to records where the ProjectId doesn't exist and update those records. Since there are many different projects each with a different projectId, I'm a bit confused as to what the update statement query would look like.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to put the "select the Top 1 projectId where the ProjectName matches" logic in a correlated sub-query:

```
UPDATE p SET ProjectID_1 = (
    SELECT TOP 1 ProjectID_1 
    FROM Projects
    WHERE ProjectName_1 = p.ProjectName_1 
        AND ProjectID_1 IS NOT NULL
)
FROM Projects p
WHERE ProjectID_1 IS NULL;
```